# What are the possible reasons why this footer appears at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

My footer seems to be appearing at the top of the page as opposed to the bottom.

I am building a landing page which requires a video background and content in the middle. When I insert the code for the footer, the footer appears at the top. I have looked over google with to no avail.

Here is the CSS I believe may be causing a issue.

```css
.contnt{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    
}


.background-wrap{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}  
#video-bg-elem{
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    
}


<!-----Css for the footer------->
  
.footer{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Please include the html

Comment: What type of element is attached to you footer class? What is telling it to be bound to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Can you able to provide html

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is missing, thus I can only guess. But it seems that your other elements in the page are not being placed with default positioning (static). If the other elements use CSS absolute positioning, they do not occupy space for the default flow. Thus, your footer (which has no absolute position rule) is the first element in the normal flow, which makes it appear at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.contnt` has `min-height: 100%`. All this means is it will try to use at least 100% of the height of it's parent element. It does not mean 100% of the height of the browser window. If the parent element is (for example) 0 pixels tall, then the child element will also be 0 pixels tall.

Try giving the parent of `.contnt` an absolute height:

```
<html>
 ....
    <div class="someContainer">
      <div class="contnt"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</html>

.someContainer {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what I see the problem is that your **footer** has not `position` set and so it uses a default one. You should try adding this to your `footer` class:

```
.footer{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    /*Add this...*/
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `width: 100%;` sets the width for your footer to be as wide as the window you have. And the `position: absolute;` makes your footer stay at an exact position. What you were missing is the `bottom: 0px;` which makes it stick to the bottom of your page.

If you want your footer to stay at the bottom of the window **all** the time, then you should instead add `position: fixed;` and again `bottom: 0px;`. That will create a footer that will stay there no matter if the user scrolls (kinda like the nav bar on StackOverflow but at the bottom).

You may also want to take a look here for more information on positioning elements with CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp